# Code stops working after convering flat MDB to SQL-linked mdb

Tags: c#, ms-access, ole

I have modified my code to count records in each table inside an mdb file. It works flawlessly, until it hits an MDB file using linked tables, which point to a SQL server. The code cannot be modified to point to the SQL server directly, it is for an in-place software upgrade scenario.

How can I modify this code to work with regular as well as linked tables?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] databases = new string[3];
            databases[0] = "data.mdb";
            databases[1] = "chunk.mdb";
            databases[2] = "transactions.mdb";

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string filename = "Results-" + dt.Hour + "_" + dt.Minute + "_" + dt.Second + ".txt";
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);



        foreach(string db in databases)
        {
                    file.WriteLine("##########BEGIN " + db + "##########\r\n");
                    Console.Write("Processing " + db + " Database . . . ");

                    string strAccessConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\financial\" + db;

                    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
                    DataTable userTables = null;
                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);

                    using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                    {
                        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\financial\DATA\" + db;
                        string[] restrictions = new string[4];
                        restrictions[3] = "Table"; 

                        try
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error opening MDB file. Please ensure it is in the correct location");
                        }

                        userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
                    }


                   ArrayList tables = new ArrayList();
                   for (int i=0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
                        tables.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());


                   foreach (string tbl in tables)
                   {
                            string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + "[" + tbl + "]";
                            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn);
                            command.Connection.Open();

                            try
                            {
                                int records = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                                file.WriteLine("{0,-45}" + records,tbl);
                            }
                            catch (OleDbException e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(e + "OLEDB Exception Occured.");
                            }

                            command.Connection.Close();
                   }


                    file.WriteLine("\r\n##########END " + db + "##########");
                    Console.WriteLine("Done!\n");
         }

            file.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(@"All Databases Complete. Press any key to continue...");
            Console.Read();  // Press any key to continue...
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe",filename);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but can I make a coding suggestion?  In `userTables.Rows[i][2]`, replace the `2` with a constant matching the name of the column, e.g. TABLE_NAME.  That way the code is self-documenting.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Error message? Exception?

Comment: @fretje, the code writes the name of each table along with it's row count to a file when run against a regular MDB. As soon as the MDB is changed to SQL-linked tables, the file is empty instead of containing table names with row counts. No errors, no exceptions.

Comment: From googling around it seems that indeed accessing linked tables in an mdb file though ADO.NET is unsupported. So I guess you'll have to go the ADO ActiveX way like Jose mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I believe that can't be done with ado.net, I had the same scenario some years ago with ado.net 1. You have to use ADOX.

here is a list of ADOX examples that can be useful 
http://allenbrowne.com/func-adox.html

ADOX does not make a difference between table and linked tables. ill take a look to my hard drive and I may post an example later.

you should execute your query with ADOX and you won't have the same problem that you have with ADO.net

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with DAO.